# NARS2000 has no documentation on how to dynamically define a function

Tags: apl

I'm frustrated by the lack of clear documentation in NARS2000.

For example, I don't know how to define a function yet.
( I know I can use trains, but that's beside the point. )

```
  AVG←{(+/⍵)÷⍴⍵} ⍝ computes the average
SYNTAX ERROR
  AVG←{(+/⍵)÷⍴⍵} ⍝ computes the average
                                       ∧
```

Then,

```
  AVG←(+/⍵)÷⍴⍵ ⍝ computes the average
VALUE ERROR
  AVG←(+/⍵)÷⍴⍵ ⍝ computes the average
            ∧
```

At this point, I really starting to wonder if NARS2000 uses `⍵` in function definition.

So how do I do define a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omega ( ⍵ ) is an identifier in NARS2000. You create a function either with the del operator or with the )EDIT command.  So if you wanted to define an avg function:

```
)edit avg
```

[0]   r←avg arg
 [1]   r←(+/arg)÷⍴arg

Control E to save, then do

```
   a←5 10 15 20
   avg a
```

12.5

Comment: Good to know there's a way to define a function in NARS2000. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Good news!  As of version 0.4.0.29 (2 Aug 2013) NARS2000 supports Anonymous Functions (a.k.a. dynamic functions).  For more details, see [the Wiki](http://wiki.nars2000.org/index.php/Anonymous_Functions/Operators).

Answer (score 1):

Darn it.

NARS2000 doesn't support dynamic functions.

The feature is on the main page under `Wish List of Features`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is some implementation of omega/alpha dynamic functions.

Here is an example:

```
      ⎕SYSVER
0.4.0.29  Fri Aug 02 06:09:58 2013  Win/32

      AVG←{(+/⍵)÷⍴⍵} ⍝ computes the average
      AVG 2 3 5
3.333333333
```